# NoReverseMatch Error on Server

Tags: python, django, url, reverse

I'm using Django 1.11, and python 2.7.
I've been stuck for hours now on an error I can't find its origin.

The error is:

```
Internal Server Error: /
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'show_news' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['general/show_news/(?P<news_id>\\d+)/$']
```

My view:

```
def list_news(request):
    news_items = NewsItem.objects.all().order_by('-submission_date')
    return render(request, 'general/news_list.html', {'news_items': news_items})

def show_newsitem(request, news_id):
    news_item = get_object_or_404(NewsItem, pk=news_id)
    return render(request, 'general/news_item.html', {'news_item': news_item})
```

My news_list.html template:

```
{% block content %}
{% if news_items %}
    {% for i in news_items %}
    <div onclick="location.href='{% url 'show_news' news_id=i.pk %}'">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">{{ i.title }}</div>
        <div class="panel-body">{{ i.body|truncatewords:20 }}
            <img height="100px" align="left" src="{{i.picture.url}}" alt="here">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">{{ i.submission_date }}</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

My urls -sorry, I was in a hurry and it slipped my mind-:

```
from general import views as general_views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^show_news/(?P<news_id>\d+)/$', general_views.show_newsitem, name='show_news'),
]
```

Locally, everything works just fine, but on the server, nothing works!
I'm really stuck. Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please update you rquestion with urls.py also?

Comment: can you drop your urls.py

Comment: Sorry about that. I was in a hurry, so it slipped my mind. I've added the url 'show_news'.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: The error is for `NoReverseMatch at /`, so you need to show the url, view and template for `r'^$'`.

Comment: @Alasdair, thank you for pointing that out. I found the problem and it was kind of silly, but thank God it's solved.
Thank you everyone for your help.
If anyone is wondering: there was non-code text in my base.html because of a merge conflict.